# Is $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\ln{x}}$ on $[0,1]$ a Lebesgue-integrable function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I have to prove that $\displaystyle x\mapsto\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\ln{x}}$ is Lebesgue-integrable on $[0,1]$. So I try to bound $\displaystyle\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\ln{x}}\right|$ with a Lebesgue-integrable function but I haven't succeed. Is there any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hints: Near $0$ there is no problem. Near $1, \ln (x) \approx (x-1).$

Comment: i think , you imply that is bounded near 1 ? because i thought this : 
$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\ln{x}}  $and then L'hospital give us   $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\ln{x}} = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{(\sqrt{1-x})'}{(\ln{x})'} =  \lim_{x\to 1} \frac {-\frac {1}{2\sqrt{1-x}}}{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x\to 1} - \frac{x}{2\sqrt{1-x}} = - \infty$  tell if i am wrong ....maybe i dont understand your hint .

Comment: Prove that if f is continuous on (a,b) and does not change sign on (a,b) then its classical and Lebesgue integral over (a,b) are equal if either of them exists.